# Como agregar nuevas columnas a una tabla Sql Oracle

Tags: oracle

Estoy queriendo insertar nuevas columnas a una tabla ya existente Sql Oracle, pero que la columna no se inserte al final, si no en medio de las columnas ya existentes

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Porque??? tenes algun requerimiento ultra particular para eso??? poque el orden de las columnas, no deberia importar nunca....

Comment: En Oracle sólo se pueden agregar columnas en la posición final; pero desde R12 si juegas con la [visibilidad](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/tables.htm#ADMIN-GUID-6AF5669A-5278-473A-A24F-3B3598110E3D) puedes obtener un efecto similar.